# In Redshift, how do you add multiple constraints to a table after creating the table?

Tags: foreign-keys, amazon-redshift, alter-table, multiple-tables

In Redshift, is there a way to add multiple constraint to an already created table?

Step ONE, created the table (say month ago)

```
CREATE TABLE test_user 
(
account_id          BIGINT DEFAULT NULL encode mostly32,
ingest_timestamp    BIGINT DEFAULT NULL ENCODE mostly32,
ingest_date         TIMESTAMP DEFAULT NULL ENCODE delta32k,
user_id             BIGINT NOT NULL encode mostly32,
group_id            BIGINT NOT NULL encode mostly32,
department_id       BIGINT NOT NULL encode mostly32,
name                VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL ENCODE LZO,
mobile              VARCHAR(15) DEFAULT NULL ENCODE LZO,
phone               VARCHAR(15) DEFAULT NULL ENCODE LZO,
user_language       VARCHAR(15) DEFAULT NULL ENCODE runlength,
deleted             INT DEFAULT NULL ENCODE mostly8,
created_at          TIMESTAMP DEFAULT NULL ENCODE delta32k,
updated_at          TIMESTAMP DEFAULT NULL ENCODE delta32k,
PRIMARY KEY (user_id)
)
sortkey (account_id)
```

Step TWO, created more tables like 'test_group','test_department'

Step THREE, after a month, I am planning to add multiple constraints to 'test_user' table like this(but in separate query)

```
ALTER TABLE test_user ADD CONSTRAINT FK_1 FOREIGN KEY (group_id) REFERENCES test_group (group_id); 
ALTER TABLE test_user ADD CONSTRAINT FK_1 FOREIGN KEY (department_id) REFERENCES test_department (department_id);
```

The above succeeds.

However, Is there a way to add multiple constraints in single query? 
Tried like this,

option 1 -> `ALTER TABLE test_user ADD CONSTRAINT FK_1 FOREIGN KEY (group_id) REFERENCES test_group (group_id),ADD CONSTRAINT FK_1 FOREIGN KEY (department_id) REFERENCES test_department (department_id);`

option 2 -> `ALTER TABLE test_user ADD CONSTRAINT FK_1 FOREIGN KEY (group_id) REFERENCES test_group (group_id), FK_1 FOREIGN KEY (department_id) REFERENCES test_department (department_id);`

But got this error for both case,

```
An error occurred when executing the SQL command:
ALTER TABLE test_user ADD CONSTRAINT FK_1 FOREIGN KEY (group_id) REFERENCES test_group (group_id), FK_2 FOREIGN KEY (department_id) REFERENCES test_department (department_id); REFERENCES helpdesk_user (user_id)

ERROR: syntax error at or near "FK_2"
```

Is there a way to add multiple constraint to an already created table?
Please help

Answer (score 7):

It doesn't matter when you define them, or even if you define them at all.

**Redshift ignores constraints**. Defining them has no effect, except that the optimizer *may* use them as additional information when creating the access plan.

However, I have created and used massive (billions of rows) databases in redshift, and I didn't define a single constraint of any kind and it all ran amazingly fast.

Answer: Don't bother.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Bohemian.  I am aware Redshift has no effect for constraints. On top of that, I want the constraints added, as I am planning to outsource the Redshift to some third party who will be accessing my cluster.  In that note, I want to add the constraints (for name sake).  Hence, do we have any other way to multi add constraints?

Answer (score 2):

The [`ALTER TABLE` documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_ALTER_TABLE.html) does not indicate that it is possible to specify multiple constraints in one statement:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
{
ADD table_constraint |
DROP CONSTRAINT constraint_name [ RESTRICT | CASCADE ] |
OWNER TO new_owner |
RENAME TO new_name |
RENAME COLUMN column_name TO new_name |
ADD [ COLUMN ] column_name column_type
[ DEFAULT default_expr ]
[ ENCODE encoding ]
[ NOT NULL | NULL ] |
DROP [ COLUMN ] column_name [ RESTRICT | CASCADE ] }

where table_constraint is:

[ CONSTRAINT constraint_name ]
{ UNIQUE ( column_name [, ... ] )  |
PRIMARY KEY ( column_name [, ... ] ) |
FOREIGN KEY (column_name [, ... ] )
REFERENCES  reftable [ ( refcolumn ) ]}
```

On a side note, [Redshift Pitfalls And How To Avoid Them](https://heap.engineering/redshift-pitfalls-avoid/) has an interesting examination of the impact of constraints on Redshift queries (see "Beware of Constraints" section).